# Mean and Variance of the Area of a Circle with Uniform Radius

Tags: probability, expected-value, density-function, uniform-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function

> A circle with a random radius R∼Unif(0,1) is generated.  Let A be its area.
> (a) Find the mean and variance of A, without first finding the CDF or PDF of A.
> (b) Find the CDF and PDF of A.

So, quite obviously, we know the equation of a circle as A = ${\pi}r^2$. If we are given a uniform distribution, can we not just find $E(R)$ and then, using that value, find $E(A)$, and likewise for the variance? And, if we have $F(A)$, is this the CDF or PDF?

Comment: Please read about [our policy](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) of answering the homework questions and edit your question accordingly. What exactly is unclear for you? What have you already tried to solve this? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Check this out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician

Answer (score 4):

Some guide:

- Notice that $$\mathbb{E}(A) \neq  \pi (\mathbb{E}(R))^2$$ in general. Hence we **can't** say that since $\mathbb{E}(R)= \frac12$, hence $\mathbb{E}(A)=\frac{\pi}{2^2}$, this is not the right approach.
- We have,
  $$\mathbb{E}(A) = \pi\mathbb{E}(R^2)$$
  and to evaluate $\mathbb{E}(R^2)$, you might like use for the formula of $Var(X)=\mathbb{E}(X^2)-\mathbb{E}(X)^2$.
- To find variance of $A$, you might want to use the same formula as well.
- $F(A)$ usually denote CDF.